# how to keep application start with device restart

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any way to start applicaiton when device restarts .

I mean - my appliaction  is trying to get location when the application is running in background, but any how if user is restart the device then application will not provide any location updates.

So is there any way to keep application running even though the device is restarted ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, iOS does not provide anything like an autostart functionality. There might be a way on jailbroken phones, but if you aim for the App Store you'll have to design your app/service that you can live with this limitation.

**Edit:** I stand corrected. If you set the `voip` value in the `UIBackgroundModes` key of your `Info.plist`, your app does get restarted after a device reboot. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22):

> `voip`:
>   The application provides Voice-over-IP services. Applications with this key are automatically launched after system boot so that the application can reestablish VoIP services.

Comment: ok . but with VOIP and Location search in background can the device will start the finding of location with restart or it is not possible to do that ??

Comment: In order for an application to get locations it must be running. Either because the user explicitly started it by tapping on the icon on the home screen, by tapping the right button in a Push Notification or by calling an URL for which your app has registered an URL handler. iOS won't start your app automatically, only through these three user interactions. Also, be aware that your app can and will get killed if it runs in the background and memory is getting low because the foreground application needs it (surfing the web is often already enough).

Comment: I have got the Solution === If you will allow Background Location services and VOIP in the plist files then application will automatically call the Applicationdidfinishloading: when device will be restarted so then we can call the location services classes - this all things are managed by device it self. we just need to write <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>location</string>
  <string>voip</string>
 </array>

Comment: @iPhone Fun: Wow, you're right. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Will Apple reject this if you are specifying that your app uses voip, but it doesn't really?

Comment: This is something I would simply risk and try since it's an official documented feature (as opposed to using private API or something).

Comment: @NickBull yes they will reject the app. In the moment you put VoIp in your plist they will want to test your app and will ask how could they place a call. They are really careful with VoIP apps.